# Exit on Error in BASH Script is not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, error-handling

I want that my BASH script exits on errors in the script. But I don't get it working.

I tried both ways, using trap and set -e, and also both at the same time.

Here is a test script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Exit on error
trap 'exit' ERR
set -e

h=1
b=$((h+)) # this produces an error
echo $?
echo $b
echo "end"
```

And the output looks like if I run the script:

```
test.sh: line 8: h+: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+")
1

end
```

Why is it not working, and how do I get each of the two ways working?

Comment: What's the point of this? the `ERR` trap and `set -e` are not here for _syntax errors._

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Wanted to know that myself, let me know if answer makes sense, because I can't find a proper reference for my solution below, to have a syntax error causing instruction and run in sub-shell or function is causing a proper `EXIT` signal

Comment: @Inian: I don't really know if it makes sense… what's the point of using a tool that's not designed for this job anyway?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Well, this is not about syntax errors. I could have used in the example also $((h+j)), and if the variable j would be empty (e.g. due to some previous problems in the script, then the cause of error is the same as in my above example.

Comment: @Jadzia: no, this wouldn't have caused any issue. In arithmetic context, an unset (or set to the empty string) variable is considered as `0`. (Unless you also use `set -u`, of course).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I see, didn't know that. But actually I have encountered the above problem in one of my shell scripts, where there was no syntax error. It was in an arithmetic expression, where I got exactly the same error as here, but one of the terms which was added was an integer delivered directly by a command substitution if I remember correctly. Anyways, I was interested here in trapping errors from built-in commands.

Comment: This is not an “error from built-in command”, this is just a syntax error.

Comment: The above example is a syntax error, which causes an error in an built-in command. And errors in built-in commands can also arise without syntax error. And this thread here is about error handling in built-in commands, not about syntax error, even though the error in the example was caused by a syntax error.

Comment: Now be careful: you can start using horrible stuff like `set -e`, `set -u`, `trap '...' ERR`, getting used to them, and then you'll think you're in security (and maybe be less careful)—and worse, sometimes you'll hit corner edge problems that will be difficult to deal with. I strongly encourage you to use the shell the way it's designed to be used: without these false security pillows. Meticulously checking every command that can potentially fail. You'll become a much better programmer that way. Use other languages if you want some sort of security.

Comment: And maybe read [BashFAQ/105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: On this point, which is another story, I completely agree with you.

Comment: Then I'm glad you're on the right track `:)`. Cheers.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Thanks also for the link, that's an interesting page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are (willfully) introducing a syntax error in the context of `set -e` and a trap.  You identify a behavior that seems unexpected regarding these.  But I do not think the issue has to do with either the trap or the shell option.

Try this (not in your script, just in an interactive shell) :

```
echo $(( H+ )) && echo OK || echo NOT_OK
```

This will fail, of course (try echo `$?` right after).  But it will not echo "NOT_OK", it will echo nothing at all, which does not seem natural at all.

Therefore, in the presence of a syntax error, the normal shell semantics break down.  You cannot assume that failure by syntax error behaves like a command returning a non-zero status, it clearly bypasses some parts of the expected shell error-handling behavior we are used to.

One more thing...  This is a syntax error in the arithmetic expression, but is not detected when the script is parsed.  It does not prevent the script from being executed (contrary to missing quotes, brackets...).

This does the same thing :

```
[[ A = ]] && echo OK || echo NOT_OK
```

But this does not (will display NOT_OK) :

```
[ A = ] && echo OK || echo NOT_OK
```

Double-bracketed conditionals are reserved words, while single-bracketed conditionals are shell builtins, so that may have to do with the difference in behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it quite clarifying! I think I understand your argument with the syntax error. So the bash script can be principally be syntax error free, but if for example some external input is used, which is not in the form as it should be, it can also lead to a syntax error. That's what has happened in my application.

Comment: I do not know if the actual shell source code would consider that a "syntax error " in the same sense as a non-matches parentheses, but it obviously fails in a way that is different from a command returning a non-zero code.  Intuitively, I would say that instead of the command returning the error code,  it could be the shell that decides there is a syntax error, stops executing the statement (all of it, bypassing what follows after || or &&), and then setting the return code itself, not using that of the $(( )) construct.  But that is just a theory.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to use `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/bash` on the first line of your script.
Else you can enable error trace in your  bash `set -o errtrace`.

From bash man page:

> the ERR trap is not inherited unless the -o errtrace shell option has
>   been enabled.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The second way seems to be very nice. But the first way with "#!/bin/sh" might be problematic since /bin/sh might be linked to another shell than bash, isn't it?

Comment: @Jadzia: With your original code, what change solved your problem, Can you edit the answer to demonstrate it?

Comment: @Inian: Actually I just assumed that it works so far, but didn't have tested it. I tested it in the now, and it does not seem to work actually. I placed the option "set -o errtrace" at the very top of the script.

Comment: I tried it, but it does not work. And even if it would, my interactive shell would quit as well if I cause an error by some type for example.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you like to increment h ? then do
b=$((h++))

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But no, I don't want to do increase h. This was just used as an example to create an error. The entire point here is about error handling.